# I want to generate a token after I verified the user phone number in Django how can I do that

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, token

I write an application which send otp from api server and it actually works but after the user verify the phone number I want to generate a token for the user and after that every time the user want to send the request he should post the token to the headers.
first I try tokenauth in rest framework but it needs user to be authenticated and it wants username and password which I can't post this to django server.
how can I do that with posting phone number and otp

this is all of my code

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.14.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "2858-151-240-216-221.ngrok-free.app",
    "localhost"
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'home',
    'requests',
    'users',
    'api',
    'otp_api'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'uploads'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication"],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
}
```

```
import random

from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializer import ProfileSerializer
from users.models import *
from utils.mixins import send_otp_on_phone


class whatsappAPI(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        serializer_obj = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_obj.is_valid():
            phone_number = serializer_obj.data.get("phone_number")
            Profile.objects.create(phone_number=phone_number)
            send_otp_on_phone(phone_number=phone_number)
            user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(phone_number=request.data["phone_number"]).values()[0]
            return Response(user_profile)
```

```
import random

from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializer import OTPSerializer
from .models import *
from utils.mixins import *


class OTPApi(APIView):
    serializer_class = OTPSerializer
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        serializer_obj = OTPSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_obj.is_valid():
            otp = serializer_obj.data.get("otp")
            phone_number = serializer_obj.data.get("phone_number")
            code_verification = check_code(otp=otp, phone_number=phone_number)
            if code_verification:
                OTPModel.objects.create(otp=otp, phone_number=phone_number)
                user_profile = OTPModel.objects.filter(otp=otp).values()[0]
                # I want here to generate the token
                return Response(user_profile)
            else:
                return Http404("invalid otp")
```

Comment: Please write correct English sentences. Start a sentence with an upper case and end with a period.

Comment: You may check `rest_framework_simplejwt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `rest_framework_jwt` package. You can just add your own function to generate the token and the payload and set some configurations for that.

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

class OTPApi(APIView):
    serializer_class = OTPSerializer
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get_token(self, obj):
        """Generate JWT Token"""
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def post(self, request):
        serializer_obj = OTPSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_obj.is_valid():
            otp = serializer_obj.data.get("otp")
            phone_number = serializer_obj.data.get("phone_number")
            code_verification = check_code(otp=otp, phone_number=phone_number)
            if code_verification:
                OTPModel.objects.create(otp=otp, phone_number=phone_number)
                user_profile = OTPModel.objects.filter(otp=otp).values()[0]
                
                return Response({
                    'token': self.get_token(user_profile),
                    'user': ProfileSerializer(user_profile).data,
                }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Http404("invalid otp")
```

And in settings.py, you need to set some configurations to let the DRF know about your JWT setting.

```
# REST framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```